# Vector Icons not working with Firebase in React Native, building on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I’ve been trying to implement vector icons with Google Firebase in react-native without success. Below are the most basic steps that lead to the error. This example uses react-native-elements and I also tried it with native-base, and ran into the same problem with vector icons.

1. git clone https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter.git myproject
2. Cd myproject
3. Yarn
4. Npm run rename
5. Create the Firebase app in the Firebase console using the package name provided in step 4
   [image: Created app in cli]
   [image: Created app in Firebase with cli info]
6. yarn add react-native-elements
7. yarn add react-native-vector-icons
8. react-native link react-native-vector-icons
9. react-native run-android
10. error with vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage 
    [image: error with vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage]

Edit: Adding MainApplication.java

```
package com.thisguy.myproject;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
// optional packages - add/remove as appropriate
import io.invertase.firebase.admob.RNFirebaseAdMobPackage; //Firebase AdMob
import io.invertase.firebase.analytics.RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage; // Firebase Analytics
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage; // Firebase Auth
import io.invertase.firebase.config.RNFirebaseRemoteConfigPackage; // Firebase Remote Config
import io.invertase.firebase.database.RNFirebaseDatabasePackage; // Firebase Realtime Database
import io.invertase.firebase.firestore.RNFirebaseFirestorePackage; // Firebase Firestore
import io.invertase.firebase.instanceid.RNFirebaseInstanceIdPackage; // Firebase Instance ID
import io.invertase.firebase.links.RNFirebaseLinksPackage; // Firebase Dynamic Links
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage; // Firebase Cloud Messaging
import io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage; // Firebase Notifications
import io.invertase.firebase.perf.RNFirebasePerformancePackage; // Firebase Performance
import io.invertase.firebase.storage.RNFirebaseStoragePackage; // Firebase 
Storage
import io.invertase.firebase.fabric.crashlytics.RNFirebaseCrashlyticsPackage; 
// Crashlytics

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) 
{
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new VectorIconsPackage(),
        new RNFirebasePackage(),
        // add/remove these packages as appropriate
        new RNFirebaseAdMobPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseAuthPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseCrashlyticsPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseDatabasePackage(),
        new RNFirebaseFirestorePackage(),
        new RNFirebaseInstanceIdPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseLinksPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage(),
        new RNFirebasePerformancePackage(),
        new RNFirebaseRemoteConfigPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseStoragePackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I face same problem while I using vector-icon with naitve-base**

**Step 1:**
Go to this file   *android/app/src/main/java/com/skillexr/MainApplication.
java*

**Step 2:**
Verify is there import vector-icon package more than one time?. If vector-icon package import more than one time, remove all and keep only one vector-icon.
Multi time import is happen whenever using react-native link.

**example:**

```
package com.xxxxx;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.goldenowl.twittersignin.TwitterSigninPackage;
import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.storage.RNFirebaseStoragePackage;
import com.goldenowl.twittersignin.TwitterSigninPackage;
import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.database.RNFirebaseDatabasePackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
  return mCallbackManager;
}

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new TwitterSigninPackage(),
            new RNGoogleSigninPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
            new RNFirebasePackage(),
            new RNFirebaseAuthPackage(),
            new RNFirebaseDatabasePackage(),
            new RNFirebaseStoragePackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Edison, thank you for taking time to reply. I reviewed the MainApplication.java file for duplicate entries, but found none. I also added the contents of that file to the question above.